# Plotting a function around $0$ shows it is jumping around, although the limit as $x\to 0$ exists

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, mathematica, indeterminate-forms

My problem revolves around the function:

$$ f(x) = \frac{\sin(\tan x) - \tan(\sin x)} {\arcsin(\arctan x) - \arctan(\arcsin x)} $$

The $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)= 1$. However, whilst approaching 0, there is a lot of sporadic oscillations (mainly between -0.005 and 0.005). I've been asked

'Since the limit exists, how do you explain the outputs from the function for "small" values of x and for the plot that you generated?'

I can't really give a justifiable reason for it other than because the top and bottom functions equal what they equal and that is what they give you, but I have a feeling that isn't what we were going for...

PS here is a graph of it for quick reference:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical example of the [loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) occurring in numerical calculations. Let's focus on the numerator. When $x=0.005$, the terms being subtracted, $\sin \tan x$ and $\tan \sin x$, are of size $\sim 0.005$ themselves. In [double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), their representation incurs errors of size $0.005\cdot 2^{-53}\approx 5\cdot 10^{-19}$.

The Taylor series of $\sin \tan(x)-\tan\sin x$ at $x=0$ [begins with $-x^7/30$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20sin%28tan%28x%29%29-tan%28sin%28x%29%29). Plugging $0.005$ in gives a number about $2\cdot 10^{-18}$: this is the magnitude that the numerator has.

So, at this size of $x$, the magnitude of the numerator is comparable to the size of round-off errors. Similar thing happens in the denominator. The result of computation is garbage.